# Performance on import packages in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, performance, import, material-ui

I am trying to understand about "import" on React. I have already read the doc.

Who can explain to me why THE COST is different between using "{" or not use it.

In this particular case, should I use it or not?

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your questions can be answered in the documentation of your package here - https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/

tl;dr: If your current framework doesn't optimize it automatically via tree-shaking, do either Option 1 or 2, preferably Option 2.